# (Multi-User) Security Key-prefixed Schnorr Signature

Tags: provable-security, schnorr-signature

Bernstein proofs in his [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/996) that single-key security of the classic Schnorr signature system tightly implies the single-key security of the key-prefixed variant of the system. Can this statement be applied also for short schnorr signatures (halved hash output length)? In other words:
Does single-key security of short schnorr signature system tightly implies the multi-key security of the key-prefixed variant of the short schnorr system?

Comment: Are you aware of https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1105 ?